# Travel through a Tree

Tags: c, arrays, list, tree

I want to create a string depending on how I travel the tree I have created.

For example.

```
Structure_of_tree{

    int value;
    char ch;

}
```

I want to cycle through the tree until I find set value.

```
create_string(int val_toFind, treeStruct *treeRoot){

   char string[10];
   for(treeRoot != null && val_toFind == treeRoot->val){
      if(treeRoot goes left)
         strcat(string,0);

      if(treeRoot goes right)
         strcat(string,1);
   }
}
```

Is this possible? The idea is that the value to find gives me an output:

```
A: 01001
```

A is the ch inside the tree and the string is '01001'.

Answer (score 0):

Your tree should have the struct as,

```
struct tree {
    int value;
    char ch;
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
};
```

Also you need to handle insert function appropriately. This is similar to binary search tree. 
Have a look at Stanford University's tutorial [here](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html).